# Setting SLIME in emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I was trying to install SLIME. I downloaded the zipped package and according to the README file, I have to put this piece of code in my Emacs configuration file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/hacking/lisp/slime/")  ; your SLIME directory
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl") ; your Lisp system
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Setting the SLIME directory is straightforward, but what about the Lisp "system"? How do I find it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some Linuxes come with CMUCL preinstalled, but since you seem to want to use SBCL, you would need to install it.

In terminal, or in Emacs <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`. If you are using Debian-like distro, you can use apt-get or aptitude with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

or

```
$ sudo aptitude install sbcl
```

on RHEL-like distro:

```
$ sudo yum install sbcl
```

After SBCL is installed, you can set `inferior-lisp-program` to "sbcl".

Also, I'd advise to install SLIME through [quicklisp-slime-helper](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-slime-helper)

You would need to install some Lisp you like (let it be SBCL for this purpose, as described above), then, in the same shell do this:

(Suppose you are on a Debian-like Linux)

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget http://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
$ sbcl --load ./quicklisp.lisp
```

wait until you see Lisp shell prompt,

```
* (quicklisp-quickstart:install)
* (ql:add-to-init-file)
* (ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")
* (quit)
```

now you are back in the regular shell. Launch Emacs, if not open yet. <kbd>C-f x</kbd>`~/.emacs`. Add the lines below to it (instead of what you posted above):

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

Or replace "sbcl" with the Lisp implementation you installed.

Look into [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation) documentation for more information. You will find that you will be using Quicklisp later anyway, so it's useful you get it all in one place from the start.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good description. Just one thing, I suppose SBCL and clisp are compilers for lisp, which of them is better? SBCL is definitely much faster. Which one should i use?

Answer (score 7):

Top answer is a little bit old.

Nowadays emacs has an official package manager. You can install slime via MELPA repository. First [setup MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started), then `M-x package-install RET slime RET`.

After that you can set your `inferior-lisp-program` like the top answer explained.