# M-x slime [No match] in emacs under mac osx

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I am learning common lisp now. I want to use slime in emacs, but when I press M-x slime it says [No match]

Initially I download the CVS snapshot and put this in my .emacs file

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/local/bin/sbcl") ; your Lisp system
(add-to-list ’load-path "~/.slime") ; your SLIME directory
(require ’slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Then I set up again followed this tread [Setting the SLIME in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607716/setting-the-slime-in-emacs)

But the problem did not disappear.

Also, M-x run-lisp does not work. When I tried to do so, buffer displayed "Searching for program: No such file or directory, lisp"

Comment: Check to make sure that /opt/local/bin/sbcl is the right path, also  do a: which sbcl on Terminal.app If it doesn't print a path back then sbcl is either not in your path and you should add it or not installed and you need to install it.

Answer (score 4):

To be safe, try installing SLIME using Emacs 24's package manager.

1. Configure package management in your init.el:

   ```
   (require 'package)

   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa"     . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))

   (package-initialize)

   (unless package-archive-contents 
     (package-refresh-contents))
   ```
2. Run `M-x package-install slime`. That should set up the load path correctly for you.
3. Those configuration options you had should now work:

   ```
   (setq inferior-lisp-program (executable-find "sbcl"))
   ```

I just did a fresh install of SLIME and SBCL and that's all it takes for me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be $PATH related. I had just

`(setq inferior-lisp-prompt "sbcl")`

in my .emacs and got this error. I changed it to

`(setq inferior-lisp-program (executable-find "sbcl"))`

and my ELPA-installed SLIME now works on my Emacs 24.3.1 under Debian

Comment: Note that the first attempt says`...-prompt` and the second says `...-program`

Answer (score 0):

In the add-to-list line, add a forward slash after slime (i.e. `~/slime/`) to make this a directory spec.

Answer (score 0):

Configure this into your init.el using `c-x c-f ~/.init.el`.

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa"     . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

(unless package-archive-contents 
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

- Reinstall both sbcl and slime.
- I used roswell for the whole setup. This [site](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b) should help.

To use slime in emacs, you add it to using `c-x c-f  ~/.emacs`.

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/.roswell/helper.el"))
```

This should all work.