# Common Lisp -- configuring slime and emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, common-lisp, slime

I am in the process of configuring slime for emacs. So far I have read about basic functionality for common lisp such as `C-c C-q` which invokes the command `slime-close-parens-at-point` which places the proper number of parens where your mouse is. Another command that seemed cool was invoked by `C-c C-c` and it would pass the code you are editing in a buffer to the REPL, and "compile" it.

**Why won't these commands work for me?**

Anyway, I have downloaded `slime` via `M-x list-packages` and do not seem to have this functionality (`C-h w` and then any of these commands tells me that these commands do note exist). So, I saw a bunch of other slime extensions such as `slime-repl', 'slime-fuzzy' and 'hippie-expand-slime'. So I again used`M-x list-packages` and downloaded them.

Still I did not have these commands. Here is the content of my emacs file relevant to slime:

```
;;;Common Lisp and Slime                                                                                                                                
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/s2s2/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20130626.1151")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/s2s2/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-repl-201000404")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/s2s2/.emacs.d/elpa/hippie-expand-slime-20130226.1656")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/s2s2/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-fuzzy-20100404")

(require 'slime)
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
     `((sbcl ("/usr/bin/sbcl"))
       (ecl ("/usr/bin/ecl"))
       (clisp ("/usr/bin/clisp" "-q -I"))))

(require 'slime-repl)
(require 'slime-fuzzy)
(require 'hippie-expand-slime)
```

When I execute `M-x slime` I get the following message in the `inferior-lisp` buffer where I can execute common lisp code (however, shouldn't this be the `slime-repl` since I required it?):

```
STYLE-WARNING: redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>) in DEFMETHOD
STYLE-WARNING:
   Implicitly creating new generic function STREAM-READ-CHAR-WILL-HANG-P.
WARNING: These Swank interfaces are unimplemented:
 (DISASSEMBLE-FRAME SLDB-BREAK-AT-START SLDB-BREAK-ON-RETURN)
;; Swank started at port: 46533.
```

Then a `slime-error` buffer is created with the contents:

```
Invalid protocol message:
Symbol "CREATE-REPL" not found in the SWANK package.

  Line: 1, Column: 28, File-Position: 28

  Stream: #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {10056B9C33}>

(:emacs-rex (swank:create-repl nil) "COMMON-LISP-USER" t 5)
```

1. How should I modify my emacs file to give me the functionality of those commands? In my emacs file am I not loading the necessary files? Do I need to install an additional package?

**Or if you have better ideas let me know!**
If you need more information let me know! All help is much appreciated!

Comment: I wrote here before about (in my opinion) an easy way to set up the environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607716/setting-the-slime-in-emacs/12609066#12609066 , perhaps you will find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swank is the server in common lisp (in your case, it's SBCL) as the backend of SLIME. SLIME is the frontend in emacs lisp.

slime-repl won't work by itself, it needs the corresponding plugin at the server side. You should ensure that there is swank-repl.lisp in the directory of swank. It's swank-repl.lisp including the "CREATE-REPL" function.

Your slime-repl doesn't work. So you cannot see the *slime-repl* buffer in emacs.

I prefer to use SLIME from the its official GIT repo (https://github.com/slime/slime).